# prove that $(a-b)(c-d)+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c) \geq 0$.

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c$  and $d$ be real numbers with $a+d = b+c$, prove that $(a-b)(c-d)+(a-c)(b-d)+(d-a)(b-c) \geq 0$.

Should I substitute in the given condition for $a$ and $b$ and see if things simplify? Or should I use the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  It seems that using substitution from the condition is a reasonable place to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $(a−b)(a−d)+(c−d)(b−d)+(d−a)(b−c)=2 (a-b) (c-d)=2(c-d)^2 \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Write $a=x+y,b=x+z,c=x-z,d=x-y$ for $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$ (exercise: why is this possible?). Then your inequality is
$$(y-z)(y-z)+(y+z)(y+z)+(-2y)(2z)\geq 0$$
After expanding you should be able to finish this.